# What is runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo error

Tags: android

I am trying to display data in listview from my precreated database but I am taking error Why do i take?

Here is my logcat:

```html
09-13 15:59:12.776  26647-26647/com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol/com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.EnYakinIstasyonlar}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol/com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.TabStations}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol/com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.TabStations}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
            at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
            at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
            at com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.EnYakinIstasyonlar.createTabHost(EnYakinIstasyonlar.java:21)
            at com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.EnYakinIstasyonlar.onCreate(EnYakinIstasyonlar.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.TabStations.onCreate(TabStations.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
            at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
            at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
            at com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.EnYakinIstasyonlar.createTabHost(EnYakinIstasyonlar.java:21)
            at com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.EnYakinIstasyonlar.onCreate(EnYakinIstasyonlar.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My error is in line 51.Here is line 51 
    Cursor c = mdb.query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

Here is my `Activity` code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.istasyonlar);

    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    try {
        helper.createDataBase();
    }catch (IOException e){
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        helper.openDataBase();
    }catch (SQLException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            dbHelper.KEY_FIRMA_ADI, dbHelper.KEY_ISTASYON_ADI,
            dbHelper.KEY_ISTASYON_ADRES, dbHelper.KEY_IST_ORAN,
            dbHelper.KEY_IMAGE};
    String table = "istasyon_info1";
    Cursor c = mdb.query(table, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);
    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.activity_tab_stations, c, new String[]{
            dbHelper.KEY_FIRMA_ADI, dbHelper.KEY_ISTASYON_ADI,
            dbHelper.KEY_ISTASYON_ADRES, dbHelper.KEY_IST_ORAN,
            dbHelper.KEY_IMAGE}, new int[]{R.id.istasyon_adi,
            R.id.ist_adi, R.id.istasyon_adres, R.id.oran,
            R.id.img});

    adapter.setViewBinder(new StationViewBinder());
    ListView liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    liste.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Why is this the `Exception` being thrown?

Comment: Please post the full call stack and maybe also the line number of the onCreate method above. It will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.emreisbarali.emrisb.mypetrol.TabStations.onCreate(TabStations.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)

Comment: line 51 is  Cursor c = mdb.query(table, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);

Comment: If you edit your post and add it there, it's gonna be easier for people to spot without going through all the comments :)

Comment: I can not add log cat it gives error How can i do?

Comment: I've edited your post for you.

Comment: Thank you I post my full log cat.

Comment: `mdb` is probably **null**. Did you assign any value to it? It's not in your posted source.

Comment: where have you initialized mdb?

Comment: private IstasyonDbAdapter dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase mdb;
    DatabaseHelper helper; I did not initialize mdb

Comment: Your "mdb" variable is probably null since your code show no declaration and/or initailization of it. Please Check.

Comment: İ initialize mdb with null but same error is appear